# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

Tags: spring-mvc

I create a spring mvc project in IntelliJ 14, just did as http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm did.But appeared this issue:No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

I googled and found some links in stackoverflow but it didn`t help.My IDE is IntelliJ 14, Maven version is 3.1.1 and My Spring Framework version is 4.1.6.

This is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my HelloWeb-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
```

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC FrameWork!");
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

My hello.jsp was located : /web/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp and its content is:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Hello Spring MVC</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>${message}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is puzzling, I set a break point in printHello() method, when I input: http://localhost:8080/test/hello.jsp in browser, as a result it goes into the printHello() method and prints "Hello, World!", but doesn`t find the hello.jsp page.

This is the result when I input http://localhost:8080/test/hello.jsp in browser:

```
Hello, World!
六月 07, 2015 11:27:11 下午 org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound     noHandlerFound
警告: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'
```

It is very strange, any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project structure is probably wrong. See both paths:

```
/test/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp

/web/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
```

they are different.

Comment: Thank you.The problem has been solved.Spring MVC 4.1.6 with  IntelliJ 14 deploys a application needn`t a application name.Access my app just through url:http://localhost:8080/hello not the url:http://localhost:8080/test/hello @Nikolay